# How to find duplicate names in a text file and display them?

Tags: files, text, document

I have a document named `names.txt` . I want to write a command that finds the most repeated name and shows me how many times this name has been repeated.In case of a the, it will show a random name of the tied names.

For example:

The `names.txt` file includes the names: jason, bob, nick, jason and alice

I want it  to show:

`2 jason`

Please help me guys!

Comment: What have you already tried? At which point did you get stuck?

Comment: I have tried different methods but i really dont know how to do it. Do you know some ways?

Comment: ... and what is the *format* of the file (comma separated? one name per line?), and what do you want to happen in the case of a tie?

Comment: The format is Comma Separated. In  case of a tie it will show  randomly one of the tied.

Comment: What are those different methods you tried?

Comment: I have tried this method:       $grep -o -E '\w+' example.txt | uniq -d

Comment: you just need `sort` before `uniq`, always.

Comment: Guys, i dont want to search for a specific name. I want the command , to find the moste repeated name and display me how many times has been repeated. In case of a tie, it will show a random name of the tied names.

Comment: This could probably be reduced. `tr , '\n' <example.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -1`

Comment: The command that you wrote, displays a      3, which is not the answer i would expect.

Comment: @PanosMikael can you show the exact contents of names.txt?

Comment: My names.txt file includes the following names in comma separated format:   miltos,panos,alex,ilias,nikoleta,vasilis,nikoleta

Comment: @PanosMikael `echo 'miltos,panos,alex,ilias,nikoleta,vasilis,nikoleta' | tr , '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -1` gives the proper results. Any reason why you changed the input from your original post?

Comment: This command is very close to what i want but i dont want to write the names but read them from a text file

Comment: @PanosMikael Then put the input into a file and use the first command I gave you. This also assumes that you have a newline character at the end of the line.

Comment: this is the write solution    :   cat <names.txt  | tr , '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -1    thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @PanosMikael Double "Useless use of cat award". `cat <names.txt` is identical to `cat names.txt` AND `cat names.txt | tr , '\n'` is identical to `tr , '\n' <names.txt`

Comment: @DougO'Neal you should write an answer summing up the solution you have developed here in the comments. This is because; one: comments sometimes disappear, two: so others can easily find this answer, and three: so that the question can be marked both answered and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This should answer the poster's problem: `tr , '\n' <names.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -1`